# What causes the io.netty.util.internal.OutOfDirectMemoryError in Spring Cloud Gateway?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway, reactor-netty

We are using the spring cloud gateway to proxy requests to the backend system. Currently, we found the following error. Does anyone know what could possibly cause the following exception?

```
2019-05-21 09:18:24.792 WARN An exception 'io.netty.util.internal.OutOfDirectMemoryError: failed to allocate 16777216 byte(s) of direct memory (used: 2046820359, max: 2058354688)' [enable DEBUG level for full stacktrace] was thrown by a user handler's exceptionCaught() method while handling the following exception:

io.netty.util.internal.OutOfDirectMemoryError: failed to allocate 16777216 byte(s) of direct memory (used: 2046820359, max: 2058354688)
    at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.incrementMemoryCounter(PlatformDependent.java:655)
    at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.allocateDirectNoCleaner(PlatformDependent.java:610)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena$DirectArena.allocateDirect(PoolArena.java:769)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena$DirectArena.newChunk(PoolArena.java:745)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocateNormal(PoolArena.java:244)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocate(PoolArena.java:226)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.reallocate(PoolArena.java:397)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.capacity(PooledByteBuf.java:120)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.ensureWritable0(AbstractByteBuf.java:299)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.ensureWritable(AbstractByteBuf.java:278)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1103)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1096)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1087)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder$1.cumulate(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:93)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1408)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:930)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:677)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:612)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:529)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:491)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:905)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

spring-boot-version: **2.1.3.RELEASE**

spring-cloud-version: **Greenwich.SR1**

reactor-netty: **0.8.5.RELEASE**